# Referencing .NET6 application from .net framework 4.8 app

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I'm trying to make references between my projects, two of them are in .net 6 and the third is my old project, in .net framework 4.8. Upgrading it is not an option for now. I'm in a context of an hexagonal architecture implementation. So :

ProjectLibrary1 (core) : .net6
ProjectLibrary2 (infrastructure) : .net6, reference ProjectLibrary1
Framework : .net 4.8, reference ProjectLibrary 1 and 2

Here my csproj :

ProjectLibrary 1 & 2 (updated after the comments) :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Framework :
[Screenshot of my config in vs studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS3sj.png)

The problem :

I have errors with the version of C#. It seems like it compile for .net 6 (with global using for example), but I have errors.

Errors "project targeting 6.0 can't referenced by project targeting 4.8"

I would highly appreciate some help, I tried a lot of solutions but it didn't work.

Edit :

---

To summarize the answers I made :

The idea behind this architecture is to migrate the code step by step into new modern and cleaned application. We have a huge codebase, a huge technical debt and no budget to rework all the app. So my idea was to use modern apps and migrate the actual code base, to end with a clean architecture made of a "modern" core and an "old" framework. What would you advice in my context ?

In my apps, I already have projects shared between dotnet 4.8 and dotnet core 3 projects. Why would it be possible with core 3 and not 6 ? Both of them have compatibility with dotnet standard 2.0, according to this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0).

Comment: Why do you have both `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworks`? Try removing `TargetFramework` from `csproj`.

Comment: "_Upgrading it is not an option for now._" Well, you could try _downgrading_ your .NET 6 projects to .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: You can (usually) reference a .net48 project from a .net60 project, as long as its references are not too boutique.  But not the other way around, .NET provides backward compatibility but not time-machine-powered compatibility.  So you'll have to move the parts of the code you cannot port into its own class library.  Albeit that the (usually) clause tends to be the hangup, hard to tell from the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native, I can't understand the expression "not too boutique".

The problem is our old application, and as we can't upgrade all the application (lack of resources), we want to upgrade part of the application. 

So, I would a not so old version of .net. I could use .net3 but isn't it out of support ? What's the best way to upgrade ? We can't make a "big bang" and change all the code.

Comment: Why do you have both `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworks`? You only need the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible, you can only reference a dotnet framework or dotnetstandard project from your 4.8 framework project.

Comment: I thought it was possible to target dotnetstandard2.0 from .net6 to make it compatible with .net4.8

Comment: If you have 3 projects, let's say A - dotnet core, B - framework, C - dotnetstandard library then you can add a reference to C from both A & B, however you cannot add a reference to A from B or vice-versa

Comment: Okay, but in my context, could I target dotnetstandard on my project 1 and 2, and use them from my web application ?

Comment: That should work, as long as your code compiles on a dotnetstandard framework(some features from .net6 won't be available)

Comment: Okay so, what should I do in order to compile in dotnetstandard ?

Comment: And is it possible to compile in .net6 for the other .net6 project, and dotnetstandard for the webapp

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both `TargetFramework` `TargetFrameworks`.
You should either have `TargetFrameworks` with both `.NET6` and `.NET2.0`, or a single `TargetFramework` with `.NET2.0`.

Comment: Done, true but it's unfortunately not solving my problem

Comment: Which one did you use? What's the error you're seeing now? We really need more information to help you